# QGIS geotiff extract world fails with AttributeError: 'ExtractThread' object has no attribute 'fileProcessed'

Tags: qgis, gdal, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I am trying extract the projection and create the world file and prj file from  a geotiff but I get a failure.

I have the GDAL plugin enabled and I know it is a geotiff with the projection embedded in the tif file. When I open it with qgis browser, it displays all of the information including the layer original source projection. When geotiff is opened in qgis it shows the coordinates correctly.

I actually can overlay another geotiff and they match up perfectly. But I get an error trying to extract the projection. Any ideas?

Error is as follows:

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

AttributeError: 'ExtractThread' object has no attribute 'fileProcessed' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\doExtractProj.py", line 111, in accept
    self.extractor.fileProcessed.connect(self.updateProgress)
AttributeError: 'ExtractThread' object has no attribute 'fileProcessed'


Python version: 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] 
QGIS version: 2.16.3 Nødebo, 7d00cae 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.16/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/john/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/john/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win32.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\apps\Python27
c:\progra~1\qgis2~1.16\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
c:\progra~1\qgis2~1.16\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg
c:\progra~1\qgis2~1.16\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg
c:\progra~1\qgis2~1.16\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg
c:\progra~1\qgis2~1.16\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:/Users/john/.qgis2//python
C:\Users\john\.qgis2\python\plugins\gearthview\ext-libs
```

Comment: Is this related to this bug report [#15348](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15348) ? If so you may try (1) Processing toolbox or (2) Delete .qgis2 folder and restart.